# How to populate deep level in the aggregate/lookup query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a list of question for a patient, each patient have an Id in mongoDB (patientId). In every question I have many comments (I separate each comment by type of comment: type = "ask" for patient send the followup-note comment, type = "reply" for doctor send reply comment) I want to return 2 arrays of comments but filter by type = "ask" & type = "reply". I do like this code below.

```
 findQuestionByPatientId(req, res, next){
        var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
          if (isNaN(limit))
              limit = 10;
          var skip = parseInt(req.query.skip);
          if (isNaN(skip))
              skip = 0;

        TextConsultation.aggregate([
            {
                $skip: skip
            },
            {
                $limit: limit
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $and:[{"patientId":ObjectId(req.query.patientId)}]
                }
            },
            {

              $lookup:
                {
                  from: "comments",
                  localField: "_id",
                  foreignField: "targetId",
                  as: "followups"
                }
           },
           {

            $lookup:
              {
                from: "comments",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "targetId",
                as: "answers"
              }
         },
           {
            $addFields: {
                followups: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$followups",
                    as: "followup",
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$followup.type', "ask"]}
                  }
                }
              }
           },
           {
            $addFields: {
                answers: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$answers",
                    as: "answer",
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$answer.type', "reply"]}
                  }
                }
              }
           },
           {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "users",
                    localField: "askToDoctor",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "askToDoctorExtra"
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "fileuploads",
                    localField: "attachment",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "attachmentExtra"
                }
            }
        ]).exec(function(err, obj){
            if(err) {
                res.send({ "data" : null,"resultCode": 0,"message":"Error : " + err });
                return;
            } else {
                if(req.query.count == "1"){
                    TextConsultation.count(objFind, function(err, totalRecord){
                        res.send({"data":obj,"total":totalRecord,"message":""});
                    });

                }else{
                    res.send({"data":obj,"message":""});
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Below is result.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c28",
            "patientId": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
            "title": "I got a flu, please give me an advice",
            "askFor": "me",
            "age": 27,
            "gender": "",
            "askContent": "My doctor, Please take care of me, I got a flu from yesteday.",
            "attachment": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c27",
            "askToDoctor": "5cc169cc7294ecd858d1e735",
            "createdBy": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
            "askStatus": "Awaiting Reply",
            "approvedBy": "",
            "approved": false,
            "createdAt": "2019-11-15T11:23:09.210Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-15T11:23:09.210Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "followups": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e0b2083caa0ed00107e1a4a",
                    "content": "sốt cao 38 độ",
                    "type": "ask",
                    "targetId": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c28",
                    "approved": false,
                    "createdBy": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
                    "followupFile": "5e9fef7e38381c00108d3ac2", // I want to populate this
                    "approvedBy": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
                    "createdAt": "2019-12-31T10:18:43.938Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-22T07:17:18.360Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e9fe85938381c00108d3ab8",
                    "content": "Test upfile",
                    "type": "ask",
                    "targetId": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c28",
                    "createdBy": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
                    "followupFile": "5e9fe85938381c00108d3ab7",// I want to populate this
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-22T06:46:49.575Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-22T06:46:49.575Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ea001e238381c00108d3ac8",
                    "content": "xxxxxx",
                    "type": "ask",
                    "targetId": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c28",
                    "createdBy": "5c80930d447df7735138693e",
                    "followupFile": "5ea001e238381c00108d3ac7",// I want to populate this
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-22T08:35:46.727Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-22T08:35:46.727Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "answers": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e0b1e81caa0ed00107e1a48",
                    "content": "OK, the weather is not good, please take care and take medicine that I give for you.",
                    "type": "reply",
                    "targetId": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c28",
                    "approved": false,
                    "createdBy": "5d1cd947231ceb95b8838c1b",
                    "followupFile": null,
                    "approvedBy": "5d1cd947231ceb95b8838c1b",
                    "createdAt": "2019-12-31T10:10:09.196Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-12-31T10:10:09.196Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
            "askToDoctorExtra": [],
            "attachmentExtra": [
                {
                    "_id": "5dce8a9d36ae900010449c27",
                    "filename": "attachment-1573816989205.png",
                    "originalName": "health_profile_01.png",
                    "description": "Doctor Consultation - Single upload",
                    "createdAt": "2019-11-15T11:23:09.210Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-11-15T11:23:09.210Z",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total": 7,
    "message": ""
}
```

I want the field "followupnoteFile" will be like below:

```
"followupFile": {
                "_id": "5db1b42720b4090010738421",
                "filename": "followupFile-1571927079085.png",
                "originalName": "note.png",
                "description": "follow-up note single upload",
                "createdAt": "2019-10-24T14:24:39.088Z",
                "updatedAt": "2019-10-24T14:24:39.088Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
```

The problem is "followupFile"is an file object, it's include "_id", "filename", "originalName" & "description" fields, so I would like to populate "folowupFile", how can I do? 
Thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you please provide sample data from which you got this above sample result, so that we could able to help you

Comment: @ Aravind: I already edit my question and provide sample data. Please take a look

Comment: Not like this. You have given the query and it's result. But haven't given the sample data on which you applied this query. Without seeing the data, it's hard to understand the query and your exact porblem

Comment: Hi @ Aravind.
I think the result returned is the best evidence for the sample data that I want to show you. So please show me how to provide sample data with your way so that I can show you more clearly